# What is the opposite of this terminal keyboard action?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, vim, terminal

Open terminal > preferences > keyboard

I have `control cursor right as \005`.  I like it! When inside Vim, it moves the page down 1 line while keeping my cursor unmoved.

Try it.

My question is: how do I do the same with `control cursor left`?  I want vim to move the page 1 line up, but keep cursor unmoved.

What is the "action" for it? I tried \004 and nothing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\005` or `\x05` is the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> in ASCII (see [C0 control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes), which represent both a control character and a keypress). The opposite, in Vim, would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, which is `\031` in octal or `\x19` in hex.

See also `:help ^E`, `:help ^Y` and `:help :map` in Vim.